Show that $\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}+\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{cb}{a}} \geq 3$
the problem
Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=1$. Show that $\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}+\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{cb}{a}} \geq 3$
my idea
The inequality would be proved if we prove that $\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}=\sqrt{\frac{ab}{1-a-b}} \geq 1 <=> \frac{ab}{1-a-b}\geq 1 <=> ab+a+b-1\geq 0$
Hope one of you can help me, because I don't know what to fo forward! Thank you!

Note that your idea won't work, eg when $ a = 0.1, b = 0.1$.

So, what is the right version of the inequality, with $\sqrt3$? It is probably best to edit the post.

@Aig I checked the source again, and the problem still says that it should be $\geq 3$. I dont know if is a kistake in the book or not...anyway, thank you for your answer.

Maybe, $a+b+c$ equals $3$, not $1$?

Your inequality is false (take $a=b=c=\frac13$). It should be $\sqrt3$ in the RHS. Then: $$\left(\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{\frac{cb}{a}}\right)^2 \ge \sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}+ \sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}\sqrt{\frac{cb}{a}}+ \sqrt{\frac{cb}{a}} \sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}} $$
$$\left(\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}+\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{cb}{a}}\right)^2 \ge 3\left(\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}+ \sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}\sqrt{\frac{cb}{a}}+ \sqrt{\frac{cb}{a}} \sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}} \right)$$
$$\left(\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}+\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{cb}{a}}\right)^2 \ge 3\left(a+b+c\right)$$
$$\left(\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}+\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{cb}{a}}\right)^2 \ge 3$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}+\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{cb}{a}} \ge \sqrt 3$$
